# Selenium: how to start Internet Explorer on private mode

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, behat, mink

I am using Internet Explorer with Selenium and Mink. The problem now is that when we execute login tests for example, the user will stay logged in and that causes the next text run to fail. For some reason it doesn't start the browser in private mode/clear the session data like it does with Chrome and Firefox.

I tried setting it to private mode in the behat.yml but that is simply ignored:

`ie:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url:  'http:///'
      default_session: selenium2
      browser_name: 'internet explorer'
      selenium2:
        capabilities:
          extra_capabilities:
            InternetExplorerDriver:
              IE_SWITCHES:
              - private`

I also tried session reset() before each scenario but it doesn't help.

How else can I make sure that Selenium always starts Internet Explorer in private mode?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@insulated` tag at feature level, this will start a clean browser each time.

Comment: sadly that doesn't seem to do anything. From what I see it resets the Sessions, but I tried doing that manually and it didn't work either..